# How to profile execution of Android apps without slowing down execution?

Tags: android, profiling

I'm interested in getting what the cpu is doing in each of the time taken when running my apps.

I know of tracedump method profiling or using ddms but it seems that it dramatically slows down the app, making the profiling not accurate.

Is there any tool like sampling every a few ms the execution of the app so that we can analyze our app without much performance overhead?

Comment: The profiling should be reasonably accurate on a relative basis. IOW, if method A takes 33% more time than does method B when method tracing is on, method A should take ~33% more time then does method B when method tracing is off. One noteworthy exception would be `native` methods, as method tracing does not descend into native code, so method tracing makes Dalvik code look much worse by comparison.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it still valid if method A contains mostly iterative loops without calling methods but method B contains deep method callings? Because it might be the case that B will suffer a lot of profiling overheads that the total time of executing B becomes much more than A when method profiling is active.

Comment: That would depend in part on the implementation of the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling tools do not count the time they spend themselves. So the only inaccuracy is the tiny overhead in transferring control between your code and the tool's code.